# How to remove halogen trim to access bulb

Tags: electrical, light-fixture, light

Ok.  I feel dumb.  I can't for the life of me figure out how to remove the trim to get to the bulb.  I don't see the three tabs indicating that it is push and turn.  It swivels a bit but not enough to get to the bulb.  Any ideas?  [image]

Comment: do you have the spare bulb

Comment: Did you try pulling on the outer trim ring? Just insert your fingernails between the ring and ceiling and pull. If it comes off it was meant to, and if your fingernails break it was not. :) Anyway, I have similar lights and when you do this, the whole thing comes out, bulb and all, you will then see how the bulb is mounted and how to change it.

Comment: @GlenYates funny...that's what I ended up doing and now I see how it was.  Looks like this is what needed to be done.  Thanks everyone!

Comment: @GlenYates please write that up as an answer so it can get accepted.

Comment: @FreeMan Ok, turned comment into answer.

Answer (score 1):

For many small ceiling lights, especially gimble mounts such as this, the bulb itself will not come out independently of the trim ring and gimble assembly. The bulb is a larger diameter than the metal ring and it is held flush to the ring with spring clips.

You will be able to push the bulb in a little, but this is just flexing the spring clip. You may also be able to twist the bulb a bit, but this will do nothing to remove it.

To replace a bulb such as this, remove the entire trim assembly by inserting your fingernails between the outermost circular trim and the ceiling, and then pulling straight down. The assembly should come out, and you will see the bulb, typically a GU10 twist and lock connected to a ceramic base with 2 wires going up to the metal can that is still in the ceiling. Turn the base about an 1/8 turn counter clockwise to remove it from the bulb. Then you should be able to pry the bulb loose from the spring clips holding it to the trim ring.

Reverse the process to install the new bulb.

Comment: Excellent! This is where answer belong. ;)

Answer (score 0):

That looks like push and turn.

Anti-clockwise for both ring and bulb.

Comment: The bulb pushes but not the ring.  The ring swivels.  But pushing the bulb doesn't let me turn.

Answer (score 0):

It could be one of the twist lock type.

Using rubber glove twist it counterclockwise by about 1/4 turn

The trick is to use two hands with rubber gloves.

Place two thumbs on the lightbulb, and the rest of your hand on the ring to stop it from turning.

Turn the bulbs with thumbs.

[image]

Comment: So the ring doesn't spin.  It's stuck.  But the fixture that is holding the bulb seems to turn.

Comment: @MichaelChen that would be bad news, you will need to disassemble

Answer (score 0):

It's really hard to spot the difference from the front, but there are at least two types of halogen spot fitting; push & twist & just pull.

[image] [image]

Try push & twist first, use rubber gloves to help twist.
If no joy, try pull; a cable tie pushed behind & gripped tight will let you pull [almost] straight. The sockets have quite a characteristic 'creak' sound as the bulb starts to come to you, so if you don't hear that, maybe it's push & twist but got stuck.

If you get to that point & still no joy, as a last resort you might have to smash it out until you can actually see the mechanism. Bag it & break with a screwdriver. You're not interested in saving the bulb, only the fitting.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough response!  I can't grip it to pull.  And when I turn it, it feels like the whole socket turns as well.

Comment: You need a cable tie for the pull, slot it up & behind, then back to the rubber gloves for a clean pull. If it won't pull square, put a screwdriver at the side it wants to tilt towards, just enough pressure to keep it straight. You can get 'sucker' grips to do this, but they should come out easy enough.